# Trigger an Event in javascript before objects finish to load

Tags: javascript, events, function, overriding

I was trying to write a global JavaScriptfunction which overrides any HTML object (`img`, `iframe`, links and so on) before it being loaded by the page. The purpose of the overiding action was to to change the `SRC` and `HREF` of these objects using the DOM to any other link.

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution to that without firstly loading the object and only then changing it by the `onload` event.

My second option was to change the `SRC` and `HREF` by matching these attributes with a regular expression and replacing the resultant values. I prefer not to do so because it's slow and consumes a lot of time.

I would be glad if someone can share with his/her experience and help me solve this out.

Comment: why would  you use javascript for this?

Comment: I want to do it with Javascript because it's going to be embedded into   external pages which i haven't written.

Bakudan - it's ok if you don't want to help.

Comment: @Niv Sela your problem is in the concept, every answer here was a nice reformulation of my DELETED comment. Still you can`t manipulate something that does not exist - the DOM should be loaded to manipulate it! So what you want is impossible.

Comment: That's what i wanna make sure.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only works within the DOM.

You could however, load the page via AJAX, get the content and do any string manipulation on it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment!
The problem is that i want to embed a script inside external pages which are being download through a proxy.
I can go over all the links and do whatever i want but i was looking for something more convinient which will not require any special threat or pharsing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify items that exist in the static HTML of the page, you cannot modify them with javascript until they are successfully loaded by the browser.  There is no way to modify them before that.  They may or may not be visible to the viewer before you have a chance to modify them.

To solve this issue, there are a couple of options.

1. Put CSS style rules in the page that causes all items that you want to modify to initially be hidden and then your javascript can modify them and then show them so they will not be seen before your modification.
2. Don't put the items that you want to modify in the static part of your HTML page.  You can either create them programmatically with javascript and insert them into the page or you can load them via ajax, modify them after loading them via ajax and then insert them into the page.

For both of these scenarios, you will have to devise a fallback plan if javascript is not enabled.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you comment!
The first option can work but i was looking for something more logic like overriding a "BeforeLoading" event ;)
The second option as i said is not not possible because I'm not the one who creates the pages at the first place.

Comment: There is no "BeforeLoading" event.  Browsers do not offer that capability.  Part of the reason for this is that browsers do progressive display as parts of the page load.  Thus, there is no single point in time where the page is loaded and can be operated on, but is not yet displayed.  They could try to notify you on individual elements (when loaded, but before display), but they do not and doing so would be somewhat complicated.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i put the smiley. According my researches i didn't find anyhing similar and that's why i came to ask the experts ;)

I know that i can do it by pharsing the page content but it's very ungainly. If you're familiar with anything that is able to change links by not using 100% regex processing it would be great :)

i wrote the following regex (which is fit to almost 90% of the cases) but it's working very slowly..

#[^\.](href|src)\s*=\s*['|\"]?(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+/*(".$domain_noend."\.(com|co\.il))?/?([^'\" <>]*)['|\"]?#sim

Comment: There is a very simple solution for this:
use Base tag in html.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @NivSela - If you're only trying to change the domain or root path and your images didn't have domain or root path on them in the first place (something that was NOT described in your question), then you could use `<base>` tag.  But, if your images/URLs have fully qualified URLs, the `<base>` tag won't affect them.  Next time, offer an actual example of the HTML you're trying to change and show before/after versions and then folks could know what options are really available.